# Can I export an app that I developed on Windows to an iphone?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I am building an app with react-native and I am also using expo. I am doing this in Windows OS and I wanted to know if there's a possibility for me to send the app to an ios device or to make it work on an iphone.
I searched on internet and it's said that you need a Mac/virtual machine/hackintosh. Isn't it possible to just export it from my pc?

Comment: No sir it's not possible without a mac/hackintosh. I know that's just sad and disappointing.

Comment: yeah.. Well thanks a lot for the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No, you can't do this**. Because mac operating system uses **xcode** to develop and test an app on ios devices that mean you must have xcode installed in your system to export the app to ios devices. Till now this is only possible with mac os, not Window and Linux.